# Parse XML using class

Tags: python

This is part of my code:

```
class MyXmlParser(object):
    ...
def parseXML(self):

    if self.attrib:
      ...
```

But with this I get error already in first line:
*AttributeError: 'MyXmlParser' object has no attribute 'attrib'*.

I'm not really sure how to solve that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not accessing the attribute on the `etree`, but in your class, so I changed the code for iterate the data parsed on your variable `doc`, and used your code to print the elements with attributes, for this purpose the following code does the job:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


class MyXmlParser(object):

    def parseXML(self):
        for elem in self.doc.iter():
            if elem.attrib:
                ...
```

Also changed the import from `etree` to `ElementTree` who is responsible for parsing the XML file.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling an unknown attribute of your class. Define it and it should work.

Self.attrib refers to the attribute *attrib* of the current object (your parser), which is never defined nor initialized.

Comment: On the first line in your if statement, you are checking the presence of the attribute of the Class itself, hence the error you get saying that MyXmlParser' object has no attribute 'attrib'.

Comment: You could try to loop on each rows returned by the self.root variable and start from here, though your initial problem had nothing to do with the parsing in itself, you could have called the self.random attr, it would have output the exact error.

Comment: Reading the data from a string:

root = ET.fromstring(country_data_as_string) and then It also has children nodes over which we can iterate:

>>> for child in root: ... print child.tag, child.attrib ... country {'name': 'Liechtenstein'} country {'name': 'Singapore'} country {'name': 'Panama'} 

Children are nested, and we can access specific child nodes by index:

>>> root[0][1].text '2008'.

You should read the doc linked by Fernando : https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html